# How to acquire DTE object instance in a VS package project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-package

How can I get DTE instance in a VS package project? It's straigtforward in addin project since `application` is being passed as an argument to `onConnection` method, but it is unclear how to get it in a package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your main Package class:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = this.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
```

Comment: If you are not in the main package, you can use this: `EnvDTE.DTE dte = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;` (or use EnvDTE80.DTE2 if you need that instead.

Comment: Further option found on the MSDN site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can get a null instance getting the SDTE service if the shell is not fully initialized. See how to handle that in this code sample:

[HOWTO: Get the EnvDTE.DTE instance from a package](https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/DtePackage)