# Using IDocumentNavigationService in own extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

We are developing an Visual Studio Addin which should allow users to jump to code positons within a new created function (of course using CodeAnalysis). Actually we can only jump to the Symbols using `VisualStudioWorkspace.TryGoToDefinition`. The underlying interface `IDocumentNavigationService` would be very helpful since it provides methods like `TryNavigateToSpan` or `TryNavigateToPosition`, but the interface is internal and so we can't get the an instance of the Navigation Service.

Is there some other service that would help us? Or does anybody know if there are plans to make the `IDocumentNavigationService` interface public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want us to make it public, just file a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). In the mean time, adapting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724025/972216) is probably the right thing to do, although in your case you can get the DTE2 interface by doing `(DTE2)GetService(typeof(SDTE))` from your package. There's other approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19107675/972216) as well.

Comment: Yes of course this is one way. At the moment I choosen another way: I created a custom WorkspaceService which interacts with the IDocumentNavigationService using reflection.

Comment: Did you at least file a bug on GitHub?

Comment: Yes I added a Issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7328). I didn't set any label/tag because I didn't know If I should do this or if one of you guys will do this.

Comment: Yep, we'll take it from there. Thanks!