# Visual Studio Extension: How to get the line on which Context Menu was called?

Tags: c#, editor, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, line-numbers

I would like to create a VS extension in which I need to know the line number the menu was called on. I found a [VisualBasic implementation](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006009.aspx) with a macro that *seems* to do this, but I don't know how to start this in C#. The goal would be to know the exact number of the line the `ContextMenu` was called on to put a placeholder icon on it just like a break point. Useful links are appreciated since I couldn't find much on this topic.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502847/is-there-any-extension-for-vs-copying-code-position

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how to use this? The first line of the example actually provided via the link, `EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;` gives me the error: 
 
_An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '_DTE.ActiveWindow'_.

Comment: To get the DTE object see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087186/how-to-acquire-dte-object-instance-in-a-vs-package-project

Comment: I have create a sample based on Sergey Vlasov's suggestion and it could return the line number where the cursor on in code editor. You just need to get DTE value with "DTE dte = (DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));" in VSIX project and replace the DTE.ActiveWindow to dte.ActiveWindow. If any question, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Thank goes to both of you, it is working perfectly. If any of you converts the comments into a proper answer so that others might find it more easily, I'm happy to mark it as an answer/upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a VSIX project and add a Command item in your project. Then add following code in MenuItemCallback() method to get the code line number.

```
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = dte.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return;
        EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction]
                    as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
        if (func == null)
            return;

        string message = dte.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName + System.Environment.NewLine +
          "Line " + ts.CurrentLine + System.Environment.NewLine +
          func.FullName;

        string title = "GetLineNo";

        VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
            this.ServiceProvider,
            message,
            title,
            OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
            OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
            OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
    }
```