# Get right instance of VS2017 for self developed extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension to replace text in the current active .cs file using a custom command that is invoked from the right click context menu in the Code Window.

Accessing the document works so far, but if I start more than one instance of VS2017, then changes which I expect to be done in the new instance are made in the first opened instance.

Is there a possibility to get the right instance to access only the current active Document no matter how many instances are open?

At the moment I get the instance with following code:

```
dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
    .GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067206/10021784) to a different question help?

Comment: You'll have to stop using GetActiveObject().  Meant only for out-of-process usage, it is never necessary in a vsix extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in the class of your package (that inherits from the AsyncPackage base class):

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE) base.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));
```

The code that you were using returns some DTE instance running on your system, not necessarily the one where your extension is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

As [Carlos Quintero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53013397/11727573) already said, you should get the DTE Object by using his example.

Lets say your extension name is YourExtension:

In my case, I added a Property in my YourExtension.cs

```
 public EnvDTE.DTE DTEObject { get; set; }
```

Then in YourExtension**Package**.cs you can get the desired DTEObject right after your package got initialized:

```
protected override void Initialize ()
{
  YourExtension.Initialize (this);
  base.Initialize ();
  YourExtension.Instance.DTEObject = (EnvDTE.DTE)base.GetService (typeof (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));
}
```

Now you can work with the DTEObject within your extension and get any Object via GetObject. In My case for example I'm getting the current instance of the VersionControlEx.