# In C# - How to get line number from cursor point?

Tags: c#, document, vsix, vs-extensibility, extensibility

I want to get the **line number** or **line content** of the line where the cursor is pointing. How can I do this?

I tried [this solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e11df0d-07b2-4053-9f46-825dc28cd30a/obtain-code-window-information-based-on-cursor-position-using-visual-studio-extension?forum=vsx) but it is deprecated for VS 2019 version. I need a solution for VS 2019 version. I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067206/6803592

Comment: I don't want it to be anyway related to context menu. I just want is, if anyone clicks on any line or we are typing something on the editor, it should detect the line number and corresponding line.